# After init scope watch is never called (ui-router)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I visit a page with:

```
<div ng-if='$stateParams.show=="previous"'>
        From
        <input type="text" ng-model="year_from" />
        <br/>
        To
        <input type="text" ng-model="year_to" />
    </div>
```

And my script that is in my controller is:

```
module.exports = function(){
  $scope.year_from = '2014';
  $scope.$watch( 'year_from', function(v) {
    console.log(v);
    console.log('from');
    $scope.get_previous_reports();
  });
}
```

I only get the definition of var v one time and it's 2014 along with the from string logged one time and the other function is never called. What am I missing?

Comment: removing <div ng-if='$stateParams.show=="previous"'> allows for those ng-models to update...whut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me waaaaaaaay too long to figure out that if you have an ng-if on a div and then have some ng-models (and I'm assuming other directives) the scope changes under that if statement. What does that scope change to? That I don't know. All I know is that I can access my stuff with a $parent call.